# Jackson serialization should ignore already included objects

Tags: jackson

So this seems like a fairly simple answer to a common problem: Infinite loop detected in Jackosn.  If, when serializing an object tree, Jackson comes upon an object it has already serialized why doesn't it just ignore it?  Is there a way to do this in Jackson, or has someone created something similar?

Why all this mucking around with JsonManagedReference/JsonBackReference, which is completely insufficent if you start serializing child objects (which need a reference to the parent) some of the time and you are serializing parent objects some of the time (which obviously doesn't want the child to refer back to itself)?

It seems like now I have to create custom views that take into account every type of circular reference and use case possible which in any non-trivial ORM is a huge task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT (October 2012)

Jackson 2.x actual now DOES support identity information handling with `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation! So the original answer is bit out of date...

---

**OBSOLETE**

Jackson does not support handling of object identity: this is a non-trivial task not so because of identifying shared objects which can be done by traversing object graph (incurring some overhead), but rather in figuring out how to include identity information; which ids to use and how. This in turn is somewhat similar to inclusion of type information, but now adds second dimension of extra wrapping to handle.
Doing this has been requested before, and some thought has gone into figuring out how to do it, but ratio of effort to benefit (i.e. number of requests, how badly it is needed) has been higher than adding other features.

So your best bet is to use wrapper objects and implement this manually, or have a look at XStream which can solve this (when enabled; it adds significant overhead in time) and also has JSON output mode using Jettison.

Implementing this manually for your use case is bit easier than solving the general case: you could start with BeanSerializerModifier to add wrapper handler that can keep track of object identities, and know what to serialize instead as object id.

Comment: Thanks for excellent explanation.  I'll try some other solutions, but they feel inelegant.

Comment: Yup, ideally this would be supported. And some smaller improvements -- like, supporting manual object ids, perhaps -- might help implementing semi-manual approach?